# Not repeated image on PHP table background

Tags: css, html-table

I use table code for my  BB forum postbit; so in this postbit table I have an image for the background but there is a problem here.  The image is repeated and its not good so I want this image to not repeat and center in my postbit table.
I used the following code to fix this problem but it does not work at all!

```
  background-repeat:no-repeat
```

So please tell me what is wrong, what can I do to fix it?

This is my postbit table code and css:

```
 <table background="images/postarkaplan/{$post['fidx']}.png" border="0" cellspacing="{$theme['borderwidth']}" class="tborder2" > .... </table>
```

The css:

```
. Tborder2 { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: auto auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
.tborder2 { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: auto auto; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The class on your element is `class="tborder2"` but your rule was for `. Tborder2`. Note the space and change in capitalization.

Comment: ok but now the image shifted to left i want it showed in center?!

Comment: Then you need to set the background-position property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position